# WebBrowser not loading my page

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a WebBrowser element in my UI, I can make it navigate to a hosted page, but when I want it to load a local webpage (which is in my solution resources), which is the exact html file hosted on internet, it just shows a blank page.

```
browser.Navigate(new Uri("test.html", UriKind.Relative));
```

If I change the UriKind or the page name it shows an error that the file could not be found, so I know the browser is finding the webpage correctly but it won't render it.

I need to do this because I want to show the page while the user is offline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the html file has a build action of `Content` you can access it directly from the install location if you set a relative path.

If you want to be able to navigate between pages or include other resources in the file (including external css, js or even images) then you'll either need to copy all the files to IsolatedStorage and view them from there or host them externally.

**Edit:**
MSDN has an article which explains copying files to IsolatedStorage, so they can be viewed in the WebBrowser control, at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431811(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: I do need the JS and images, but not navigation since it's just an HTML with all the content I need (100+ images), how should I do the IsolatedStorage procedure? (copying and accesing), thx

Answer (score 0):

The browser cannot read a resource from your App/Dll.  However, it you have the file in the same folder as you application you could do:

```
 var home = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase;
 browser.Navigate(new Uri("file://" + home + "/test.html");
```

Comment: I get a "System.MethodAccessException" when the system is creating the home variable :S Additional information: Attempt to access the method failed: System.Reflection.Assembly.GetName()

Comment: This sounds like security restriction on windows phone 7.  I have never used this plantform.  Hopefully, someone out there will enlighten us.

Comment: WP7 doesn't support the "file://" protocol